# How do I assign instance of Groovy class to variable in Java class

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a Groovy class like this:

```
package com.hello

class MyClass {
    def myMethod() { println "hello" }
}
```

And I want to use this class in a Java class:

```
package com.hello

public class OtherClass {
    MyClass myc;

    public void myOtherMethod {
        myc.myMethod(); // <-- Raises NullPointerException
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it throws a `NullPointerException` because `myc` is null. When I try this:

```
...
MyClass myc = new MyClass();
public void myOtherMethod {
    myc.myMethod(); // <-- Raises NullPointerException
}
...
```

I still get a `NullPointerException`. How do I use this groovy class in my java class?

Comment: What's your actual code? The second example isn't Java

Comment: Maybe thats my problem. How do i use the groovy class in a java class.

Comment: Just like any other java class. I don't really see how the second snippet would throw an NPE, but it doesn't compile in the first place.

Comment: this is why java is a terrible language...

Comment: No, you're just doing it wrong.  But it's impossible to advise you how you're doing it wrong from the question

Comment: You can't use groovy in java class, the other way around works though. Regardless of what language you use, it is important where you instantiate the object and whether or not the methods have access to that object. Where do you instantiate MyClass?

Comment: @Armaiti You can create an instance of a groovy class in a Java class just fine

Comment: @tim_yates this looks like valid java to me. i dont know what to fix.

Comment: There's no semi colon after `MyClass myc = new MyClass()`

Comment: seriously? pretend its there. what else is wrong?

Comment: the code you show cannot cause the exception you say. The code you show cannot compile. Therefore, your code is not the code you show. This is stackoverflow. Not PsychicOverflow. If you want answers to your problems, you need to accurately describe your problems with simple examples that exhibit your problems. The above code (even with a pretend semicolon) cannot give you the exception you describe

Comment: the code compiles for me.

Comment: The second code you provide just can't compile as pure Java: you forgot the `()` after the method. It works for Groovy (it's a closure) but not for Java (syntax error).  Where is the link with Grails ? Are you trying to do this on a controller or service ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.hello

    public class OtherClass 
    {
         MyClass myc=new MyClass();

        public void myOtherMethod() {
            myc.myMethod();
        }
    }
```

Where OtherClass is Java should work just fine regardless of MyClass being groovy or Java.

If you are still getting an NPE with this code on the call to myMethod() then you have a build problem.. Try the following:

- recompile your groovy code into a class
- recompile the java to a class, make sure your groovy class is available to javac at the time.
- If you run with java, be SURE that the groovy-all jar is in your classpath (If you run it with groovy this will be automatic)

The easiest way not to deal with build problems (or put off dealing with them) is to code in eclipse with the Groovy plugin and run straight from Eclipse, that should always work.

Comment: And by the way, being restrictive and not compiling when your code is ambiguous is a huge advantage to a large team working on the same codebase, however working alone or being new to coding, groovy can be much more comfortable.  It took me years to figure out that there can't be a best language, there are dozens of best language for thousands of different types of problems. Java, R, Bash, Groovy, C, C#, Ruby, Perl, VB and even APL ... ALL have cases where they excel.